# Create arguments and forward from variadic type template

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to create arguments out of a variadic template and forward it to a stored function. If the arguments are `(typename... Args)` I want to iterate each type and fetch an argument of that type from a storage container and then forward the arguments to a function.

I've tried different methods but always end up with that I cant store an untyped vector of arguments and I can't forward a vector as seperated arguments.

This is some pseudocode-ish of what I want to accomplish.

```cpp
template <typename S, typename... Args>
void store_lambda() {
    vec.push_back([this]() -> void {
        ArgumentList arguments;
        (get_arguments<Args>(arguments), ...);
        my_function(arguments...);
    });
}

template <typename T>
void get_arguments(ArgumentList& arguments) {
    arguments.append(inner_storage.get<T>();)
}

void my_function(SomeStruct& s, const AnotherStruct& as) {
    // do something with arguments
}
```

The type `ArgumentList` is not implemented (and probly is impossible to do) but this is the system I'm trying to create.

**EDIT: More explaination**

This is how my system looks atm:

```cpp
struct WorkerWrapperBase {
   public:
    virtual ~WorkerWrapperBase() {}
}

template <typename... Args>
using exec_fn = std::function<void()>;
template <typename Job>
using job_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Job>;

template <typename J, typename R = void, typename... Args>
struct WorkerWrapper {
    exec_fn<Args...> fn;
    job_ptr<J> job_ptr;
    WorkerWrapper(J* job, R (S::*f)(Args...) const)
        : job_ptr{job_ptr<J>(job)} {
        fn = [this, f]() -> R {
            (job_ptr.get()->*f)(/* send arguments fetched from Args as explained above */);
        };
    }
};

struct CollectionOfWorkers {
    std::vector<WorkerWrapperBase> workers;
    template <typename Worker>
    void add() {
        workers.push_back(WorkerWrapper(new Worker(), &Worker::execute));
    }
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```cpp
struct TestWorker {
    void execute(SomeStruct& s, const AnotherStruct& as) const {
        // do something with arguments
    }
}

CollectionOfWorkers.add<TestWorker>();

// and then somewhere we can loop each Worker and call their execute function
```

I want to create a clean API where you can create a Worker with a simple struct containing an execute function. The types of the parameters will then be used to try to get the reference of an instance of each type thats stored in a container. And then send it to the execute function. The idea was taken from this [Game Engine talk](https://youtu.be/W3ViIBnTTKA?t=4322)

Comment: Are you looking for `std::tuple` and `std::apply()` ?

Comment: Solving this problem requires knowledge of two things: 1) where are the arguments coming from originally, and 2) where is that function coming from? Could you provide an example usage / an explanation of what task you’re trying to use this for?

Comment: I’ve done a lot of stuff that’s very similar to what you’re trying to do; I just don’t have a very clear idea of what it is that you’re trying to do

Comment: @JorgePerez added some more explaination

Comment: Have you looked at std::tuple?  You can also type-erase using std::function.

Answer (score 0):

We can bind together a function and arguments to be called later very easily:

```
auto bind_args = [](auto&& func, auto&&... args) {
    return [=]() mutable {
        return func(args...); 
    };
};
```

And we can erase this type so it can be executed later easily too:

```
template<class Ret = void>
struct FuncInterface {
    virtual ~VirtualFunc() = default;
    virtual Ret operator()() = 0; 

    // Provided to allow concrete classes to copy themselves
    virtual FuncInterface* clone() const = 0; 
};
template<class Ret, class Func>
struct ConcreteFunc : public FuncInterface<Ret> {
    Func func; 
    Ret operator()() override {
        func(); 
    }
    FuncInterface* clone() const override {
        return new ConcreteFunc<Ret, Func>{func}; 
    }
};
```

Let's add a helper function to make concrete funcs using `bind_args`:

```
auto makeConcrete = [](auto&& func, auto&&... args) {
    using Func = decltype(bind(func, args...)); 
    using Ret = decltype(const_cast<Func&>(bind(func, args...))());
    return ConcreteFunc<Ret, Func>{bind(func, args...)}; 
}
```

We can write a wrapper class that automatically handles ownership:

```
template<class Ret>
struct AnyFunc {
    std::unique_ptr<FuncInterface> func; 
    AnyFunc() = default;
    AnyFunc(AnyFunc const& f) : func(f.func->clone()) {}
    AnyFunc(AnyFunc&& f) = default; 

    explicit AnyFunc(FuncInterface* func) : func(func) {}        

    Ret operator()() {
        return (*func)(); 
    };
};
```

And then we can write a WorkerContainer:

```
struct WorkerContainer {
    std::vector<AnyFunc> funcs;

    template<class Worker, class... Args>
    void addWorker(Worker&& worker, Args&&... args) {
        auto func = [=](auto&&... args) {
            worker.execute(args...); 
        };
        FuncInterface* ptr = new auto(makeConcrete(func, args...));
        func.emplace_back(ptr); 
    }
};
```

If you have defaulted values for arguments, you can re-write this to provide them like so:

```
template<class... DefaultArgs>
struct WorkerContainer {
    std::vector<AnyFunc> funcs;
    std::tuple<DefaultArgs...> storage; 

    template<class Worker, class... Args>
    void addWorker(Worker&& worker) {
        auto func = [=, This=this]() {
            worker.execute(std::get<Args>(This->storage)...); 
        };
        FuncInterface* ptr = new auto(makeConcrete(func));
        func.emplace_back(ptr); 
    }
};
```

Comment: not sure if I'm missing something but this would require the user to manually reference the args like this `WorkerContainer.add(new TestWorker(), storage.get<SomeStruct>(), storage.get<AnotherStruct>());` while I'm trying to simplify it by getting the args dynamically knowing the types of the functions parameters

Comment: I added an example showing how to get them from storage

Comment: Well, using `std::function` would simplify things. As an aside, you leak memory if re-allocation throws, maybe at other times too.